# How to update ejs file with fetch? Using node.js and javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am trying to update an ejs file. What I am trying to do is simply to change the text in the h1 tag with the data from a get request sent with fetch. But nothing happens. If I type in the url path in the browser everything works fine, but when using fetch the server gets the data, but nothing is changing on the page.

My guess is that this has to do with using the fetch method? Is that correct? Is it not possible to use fetch? If so, how do you do it instead?

Here is my code:

**Ejs:**

```
<input type="text" id="surveyName" placeholder="Name your survey">
<div id="addQuiz" onclick="newQuiz()">Add</div>
<h1>Survey: <%= data.userQuery %></h1>
```

**The fetch get request:**

```
const newQuiz = () => {
    const name = document.getElementById("surveyName").value

    fetch(`/${name}`)
    .then((data) => {
        alert('sent!')
    })}
```

**Routing in node:**

```
app.get("/:userQuery", (req, res) => { 
  console.log(req.params.userQuery)
  res.render('home',{data: {userQuery: req.params.userQuery}}) 
});
```

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: … and using a `div` instead of a `button` to create a control that is intended to be clicked on to make something happen causes all kinds of accessibility issues

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the response to the HTTP request as a whole new page then **don't use Ajax**. The whole point of Ajax is that it makes a request with JavaScript and makes the response available to JavaScript **without** navigating to a new use.

Use a regular HTML form submission instead.

---

If you want to use Ajax then you need to use a [body interface method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#Body_Interface_Methods_2) to deal with the response body and then use that data to [manipulate the existing document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents). If you do that then you'll probably be better off making the request to an endpoint that returns the data as JSON and not one that injects it into an EJS template. You might want to read [MDN's guide to using fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Comment: I understand, but I do not want to go to a new page, I just want to change the h1 tag on the same page without rendering a new one. This is why I tried fetch. Is ejs only working with form submission?

Comment: You can use EJS to generate the response to any HTTP request. It's just rarely a good approach when dealing with Ajax. Hence why I said "better off" instead of making any suggestion that you *need* to change.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you- 
**Ejs:**

```
<input type="text" id="surveyName" placeholder="Name your survey">
<div id="addQuiz" onclick="newQuiz()">Add</div>
<h1 id="some_id">Survey: <%= data.userQuery %></h1>
```

**The fetch get request:**

```
const newQuiz = () => {
    const name = document.getElementById("surveyName").value;

    fetch(`/${name}`)
    .then((data) => {
        alert('sent!');
        document.querySelector("#some_id").innerHTML = data.userQuery;
    })}
```

**Routing in node:**

```
app.get("/:userQuery", (req, res) => { 
    res.json({userQuery: req.params.userQuery});
});
```